# What kind of product operator appears in the chain rule involving a derivative wrt a matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

Let $$y = Ax$$ $$z = y^Ty$$.

Per the chain rule, $$\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{A}} = \frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{A}} \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}} $$

Since,

$$\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{A}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial{A}}(x^TA^TAx) = 2yx^T$$

$$\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{A}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial{A}}(Ax) = x^T \otimes \Bbb{I}$$

$$\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}(y^Ty) = 2y$$

It means that,

$$2yx^T = (x^T \otimes \Bbb{I}) \text { mystery product operator } 2y$$

What is the mystery product operator ?

Answer (score 1):

Using index notation it's easier to see what's going on
$$\eqalign{
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
y_i &= A_{ip}\,x_p \\
\grad{y_i}{A_{jk}}
 &= \grad{A_{ip}}{A_{jk}}\;x_p \\
 &= \delta_{ij}\delta_{pk}\,x_p \\
 &= \delta_{ij}\,x_k
}$$
where $x_k$ is the $k^{th}$ component of the $x$ vector and
$\delta_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$ component of the identity matrix. The resulting quantity is a **third-order tensor**.

So you don't need the Kronecker product $(\otimes),\,$ but rather
the dyadic (aka tensor) product $(\star)$
$$ \frac{\partial y}{\partial A} = I\star x $$
Although some authors (especially in certain engineering disciplines) use the $(\otimes)$ symbol to denote the tensor product.

The chain rule uses an ordinary dot product $(\cdot)$
$$\eqalign{
\grad{z}{A}
 &= \gradLR{z}{y}\cdot \gradLR{y}{A} \\
 &= \LR{2y}\cdot \LR{I\star x} \\
 &= \LR{2y\cdot I}\star x \\
 &= {2y\star x} \\
 &= {2yx^T} \\
}$$